# How to get into Docker image filesystem when Container Won't run

Tags: node.js, docker

What's the best way to troubleshoot a container which won't start that fails on a filepath?  I need to peak into the image somehow and list out and see if the directories and what file structure is actually internal to the container/image after I start it but if it fails to start I'm sorta out of luck right?

```
▶ PORT=8080 && docker run -p 9090:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} gcr.io/ssss/s@sha256:5ad05d1d37baae8f548b08a41fa7c5d69465adb8acd4cc9b1703f2ed4ee361ec
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/ssss-1349/ssss@sha256:5ad05d1d37baae8f548b08a41fa7c5d69465adb8acd4cc9b1703f2ed4ee361ec' locally
sha256:5ad05d1d37baae8f548b08a41fa7c5d69465adb8acd4cc9b1703f2ed4ee361ec: Pulling from ssss-1349/ssss
cbdbe7a5bc2a: Already exists
15f7fe915f93: Already exists
3cae4fa026a7: Already exists
bfa729779926: Already exists
db6f693f3456: Pull complete
2e4c635245d4: Pull complete
6017db5d3271: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5ad05d1d37baae8f548b08a41fa7c5d69465adb8acd4cc9b1703f2ed4ee361ec
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/ssss-1349/ssss@sha256:5ad05d1d37baae8f548b08a41fa7c5d69465adb8acd4cc9b1703f2ed4ee361ec
yarn run v1.22.4
$ node --optimize_for_size --trace-warnings --experimental-json-modules --no-warnings ./server/server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/dist/server/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It's saying `'/dist/server/server.js'` is not there but I know it has to be, I copied it and so I need to peak inside the OS of the container and look around somehow to see what the file structure actually is to try to troubleshoot it

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine
ENV PORT 8080
WORKDIR dist
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Comment: I ended up just running bash commands from either the Dockerfile or from run commands in CI which also helped me troubleshoot it.  Took longer but worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility to enter a container would be "overwriting" the default command by calling a shell and invoke your desired commands it hand (as you would do in a "normal" shell). This allows you to work in your docker container like you would do in any normal Linux shell.

*Have a look at the [-interactive, -i](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) option for `docker run`.*

---

**Example**

If you want to start your container, you can run e. g. run a `bash` (...or `sh`, or whatever shell you are using):

```sh
docker run -it <img_name> <arguments> bash
```

You specified `CMD` will get overwritten.

> If the user specifies arguments to docker run then they will override the default specified in CMD.
>
> *From the [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):*

This allows to work in you container without messing up you `Dockerfile`.

---

**Additional Information**

This also works with `exec` when yyour container is running.

```sh
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

---

*Edit*: Also note the following with your command: `CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]`

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell
>
> *From [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd))*

If you want tho run the command in a shell, cosinder the following:
`CMD [ "sh", "-c", "yarn", "start" ]`

Answer (score 1):

I often use this `.sh` file to extract the content of a Docker image. `$1` is the image name. You can modify the path to the directory you want to extract to.

```
Image=$1
ContainID=$(docker run -d $Image)
docker cp $ContainID:./dist ./dist
docker rm -f $ContainID
```